# Apache Long Running Process Internal Timeout

Tags: java, ajax, apache2, tomcat7

I am developing a web application that allows users to run AI algorithms on a server remotely to decrease wait time for solutions. Here is an outline.

`Browser -> jQuery AJAX -> Apache2 proxy -> tomcat7 -> RESTful java -> Runtime.getRuntime().exec() -> command-line C algorithm`

the restful service returns desired information via AJAX response and some handling happens on the browser.

This works fine for most of the algorithms that I have tested. Some of the algorithms, however, will timeout after a very long time running. I have a live status update implemented, so the algorithm is still running and generating output constantly on the browser, but after 5 minutes or so, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Killing the algorithm process from the command line also results in a 500 Internal Server Error.

Running the algorithm directly from the command-line results in proper execution.

Sending an AJAX call to a restful method that sleeps for an hour results in a 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable) error.

What else could be the cause of this? I've been troubleshooting for a hot minute and am all out of ideas at the moment.

Thanks for your help!

--EDIT--

I have developed a workaround that efficiently solves the problem, however, I am still interested to know what anyone else thinks. Eliminating the long-lasting AJAX call and replacing it with a repeating call to check on the status of the algorithm through an alternate status file works with long running processes.

But, why previously would I have had a problem with an AJAX call specified never to time out..?